# weird Double bug on first time install? (Android)

Tags: android, android-fragments, double, sharedpreferences

I am developing an app that keeps track of nutritional information about food that the user eats in a day. I'm using the Double data type for both info about nutritional value from the food itself and nutritional value eaten in a day so I can display the information more accurately (for example 12.7g/protein per 100g, instead of 13g/protein per 100g). To save and increment the data even when the user closes the app I make use of SharedPreferences, which works perfectly fine.

However I've encountered a really weird bug where if the user installs my app for the first time the amount of calories eaten on a day is equal to 30.7 and the amount of fats eaten on a day is equal to 0.4. This happens when I run the app on my Phone, delete it of off my device and then reinstall it using Android Studio. I naturally expect all nutritional value eaten in a day to be equal to 0 upon installing the app since the user did not add any values yet.

My MainActivity contains a Fragment called DailyIntakeActivity (I know it's not an Activity) which upon calling it's OnCreateView sets the TextView to the Double data given by SharedPreferences. Again the user has not added any values to SharedPreferences at this moment, so I expect it to display 0 in all TextViews.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_daily_intake, container, false);

    Calories_text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Calories_text);

    protein_text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.protein_text);

    carbs_text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.carbs_text);

    fats_text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fats_text);
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);

    CTX = getContext();

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SPCalories = Double.longBitsToDouble(sharedPreferences.getLong("Calories", Double.doubleToLongBits(0)));
    SPProtein = Double.longBitsToDouble(sharedPreferences.getLong("Protein", Double.doubleToLongBits(0)));
    SPFats = Double.longBitsToDouble(sharedPreferences.getLong("Fats", Double.doubleToLongBits(0)));
    SPCarbs = Double.longBitsToDouble(sharedPreferences.getLong("Carbs", Double.doubleToLongBits(0)));

    DecimalFormat db = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
    db.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);

    if (SPCalories != 0) {

        dc_text = db.format(SPCalories);
        dp_text = db.format(SPProtein);
        d_cartext = db.format(SPCarbs);
        df_text = db.format(SPFats);
    }

    else if (SPCalories <= 30.7 && SPCalories > 30.6){
        dc_text = Integer.toString(0);
        dp_text = Integer.toString(0);
        d_cartext = Integer.toString(0);
        df_text = Integer.toString(0);
    }
    Calories_text.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.Calories), dc_text));
    protein_text.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.Protein), dp_text));
    carbs_text.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.Carbs), d_cartext));
    fats_text.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.Fats), df_text));
```

as you can see I already tried to fix this by telling the program that if SPCalories is smaller than 30.7 and bigger than 30.6 the TextViews should display the number 0, unfortunately this doesn't work.

Now for context the way the user adds values to the SharedPreferences is by opening a second activity and filling in numbers in an EditText, these numbers are then saved as a Double data type into SharedPreferences and then get read in the DailyIntakeActivity Fragment inside my MainActivity. Because the bug occurs even when the user has not openend the activity yet and because this question is already really long I feel like it is unnecessary to include it's code here.

Please tell me if you have any suggestions for me and have a nice day!

Vidal

Comment: `Double.doubleToLongBits(0)`. Replace by `0` or 0L. getLong() expects a long. Double to long bits? Never heard of. What should it do? And double to long?

Comment: I see, thanks for replying. I must have confused myself over the parameters in the method

Comment: Well does it help? Was it the reason for the error?

Comment: I just tried to run it but it doesn't change the problem, sorry :( however the app doesn't crash or anything so thanks for noticing this minor mistake :)

Comment: `SPProtein = Double.longBitsToDouble(sharedPreferences.getLong()`.  You did not tell what longBitsToDouble is good for. I would replace the statement with SPProtein = (Double)sharedPreferences.getLong().

Comment: Well I use longBitsToDouble because I cannot insert Double values directly into SharedPreferences. To insert a Double in SharedPreferences I have to convert a double to a long and to read that Double I have to convert the long to a double, which is what I do when I initialise SPProtein. And so the method you just suggested doesn't work because when I replace my original method with what you just suggested I get an error telling me 'inconvertible types: cannot cast long to java.lang.Double'.

Comment: Mmmm think you should try SPProtein = (double)sharedPreferences.getLong().

Comment: Sorry, that also doesn't help either. I changed Double to double but now when I start up the app the amount of calories for the day is something like 4 trillion, whereas using my old method it's just 30

Comment: Again it's not like using my original methods doesn't make it work at all or anything it's just that a value is already written in my shared preferences when the user first installs the app

Comment: Try with SPProtein = (double)0; or SPProtein = (double)0L;. What do you get? How did you declare SPProtein?

Comment: I tried but I didn't expect it to work and unfortunately it did. Now the text views all display null

Comment: Try to display sharedPreferences.getLong() directly. So without conversion to double.

Comment: And Ive written down the code from  your most recent comment exactly as you had written it down

Comment: Nope, sorry. Now I get 4 trillion again :(

Comment: Are you really deinstalling your app everytime?

Comment: Please show how you put that long in a textview.

Comment: Yes, what I do is delete it from my device by swiping the app Icon to uninstall in the navigation drawer, and then I run it again in Android Studio all using the same test device

Comment: double SPCalories;
    String dc_text;
    TextView Calories_text;
        Calories_text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Calories_text);
        SPCalories = sharedPreferences.getLong("Calories", 0);
DecimalFormat db = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
        db.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);            dc_text = db.format(SPCalories);
        Calories_text.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.Calories), dc_text));

Comment: sorry i could not click on enter or else the comment would post already

Comment: Just put that long in a textview. Dont use ceiling, rounding  or format or whatever.